# How to retain use of a child classes method after being made a pointer to the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

When I make an `Animal` pointer to hold a `Duck` object and use a method `make_choice` that returns an `enum`, it looks as though the method belonging to the base `Animal` class is being used instead of the derived `Duck` class. How do I instead retain use of the derived classes method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

enum Choice{None, Egg, Bone};
class Animal {

protected:
    std::string noise = "None";
public:
    Animal() = default;

    virtual ~Animal() = default;

    virtual std::string getNoise() {
        return noise;
    }

    virtual Choice make_choice(){
        return None;
    }

};

class Duck : public Animal {
public:
    Duck() {
        noise = "Quack!";
    }

    Choice make_choice() override {
        return Egg;
    }
};


int main() {
    Duck duck;
    cout << duck.make_choice() << endl; // should be 1 for Egg
    std::shared_ptr<Animal> duckPtr = std::make_shared<Animal>(duck);
    cout << duckPtr->make_choice() << endl; // also should be 1 for Egg, but is 0 for None
    return 0;
};
```

Output:

```
1 // for Egg
0 // for None
```

Comment: Change `std::make_shared<Animal>(duck);` to `std::make_shared<Duck>(duck);`

Comment: But what if the pointer later needs to be stored in an array of `Animal` pointers?

Comment: No, just change the right hand side, don't change the left hand side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_shared<Animal>(duck);` did not make a `Duck`. It made an `Animal` by making a copy of `duck` and [Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) away everything that makes a `Duck` different from an `Animal`.

You want

```
std::shared_ptr<Animal> duckPtr = std::make_shared<Duck>(duck);
```

or just

```
std::shared_ptr<Animal> duckPtr = std::make_shared<Duck>();
```

Addressing *But what if the pointer later needs to be stored in an array of Animal pointers?* from the comments,

```
std::shared_ptr<Animal> animals[2];

animals[0] = duckPtr;
```

is perfectly legal. No extra work is required.